# React state changes, but component doesn't rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have `svg` and when I click on it, a line is added:
line:

```
const Line = (props) => {
    const { x1, y1, x2, y2, scale } = props

    return (
        <line x1={x1 * scale} y1={y1 * scale} x2={x2 * scale} y2={y2 * scale}
            style={{ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 3, strokeLinecap: "round" }}></line>
    )
}
```

This is how I add lines (100, 100, 200, 200 are just sample numbers):

```
setContent([...content, <Line key={'line' + svgRef.current.childElementCount} scale={params.scale} x1={100} y1={100} x2={200} y2={200} />])
```

```
<svg>
    {content}
</svg>
```

But when the `params.scale` changes, the component doesn't rerender.
This is how i change the state (multiplier is a float number):

```
setParams({...params, scale: params.scale * multiplier})
```

Comment: Don't put elements in state. Only put data in state, and render elements based off that.

Comment: Ok? You're still putting elements in state. `setContent([...content, <Line` don't do this. Put data in state, not elements.

Comment: @AndyRay How should I add elements? insertAdjacentHTML?

Comment: Are you asking how to render an array of data into components in react?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem would be from setting content
you set content state and it won't be reset per se by changing param state

I think you need to use useEffect and params.scale as dependency

sth like this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setContent([...content, <Line key={'line' + 
     svgRef.current.childElementCount} scale={params.scale} x1={100} y1= 
      {100} x2={200} y2={200} />])

},[params.scale])
```

Comment: Not really, because this useEffect would add a line everytime the state changes, but I want it not to be added, but to change its attributes

Comment: you are right, how about setting value of content again 
in each changes of params.scale your array will be created again ?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for the best solution. Probably i am missing just one line of code, but if I don't find any other solutions, I will do something like that.